# Taraweeh or Salat after Ramadan

Tags: ibadah, taraweeh

Is there any prayer after Ramadan that can be prayed in the replacement of Taraweeh ?

For example, If I want to continue the Ramadan tradition outside of Ramadan, I can accomplish fasting, but how would I accomplish Taraweeh?

Is there any where in the world where they pray taraweeh after Ramadan?

Comment: You can pray Tahajjud in the depths of the night.

Comment: Note: Even though you can fast outside of Ramadan and pray Tahajjud, these things don't bring the same level of reward as the actual Ramadan ibadah. Just FYI.

Comment: I am talking about not the reward, but just the practice. If I wanted to lead 20 rukah nafl prayers with each prayer being 2 rukah. Is that possible? I am talking about as a whole group of people reading just like taraweeh and reciting the quran from beginning to end? Thanks